# Should I connect my two GPUs with SLI or not? (for Keras + TensorFlow)

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, gpu

I have two GPUs, NVIDIA GTX 1070 Ti. For using Keras with TensorFlow back-end, should I connect them with SLI or not? If not, then they will be treated separately, and one model will be trained on one card. These are the two options from what I understood so far. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not connect GPUs via SLI.  Keras and TensorFlow will take care of distributing batches across GPUs

https://keras.io/utils/#multi_gpu_model

Instead of SLI, if you use NV-link, Keras can use use GPU for merge as well. 
https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/data-center/nvlink/

From the documentation :

> Specifically, this function implements single-machine multi-GPU data
>   parallelism. It works in the following way:
>
> Divide the model's input(s) into multiple sub-batches. Apply a model
>   copy on each sub-batch. Every model copy is executed on a dedicated
>   GPU. Concatenate the results (on CPU) into one big batch. E.g. if your
>   batch_size is 64 and you use gpus=2, then we will divide the input
>   into 2 sub-batches of 32 samples, process each sub-batch on one GPU,
>   then return the full batch of 64 processed samples.
>
> This induces quasi-linear speedup on up to 8 GPUs.
>
> This function is only available with the TensorFlow backend for the
>   time being.